# Div Background Isn't Getting Set

Tags: css, html

```
#contentwrapper {
   background: #111;
   background: url('~/img/bg-black.png');
   width: 100%;
}
#content {
   width: 340px;
   height: 165px;
   margin: 240px auto;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
<div id="content">
<h1 style="text-align: center">Test</h1>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I m trying to set the background image of contentwrapper to the given link, but when I run it, it doesn't get shown. I tried rewriting, reloading, readding, etcetera. Nothing works

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the tilde (`~`) character, and map it from the root of the site. You can also try removing the quotes or using double quotes, but it should work either way:

```
background: url(/images/dialog-gradient-beige.png);
```

If you can't map it from the root of your site, try backing out to the images directory:

```
background: url("../images/bg-black.png");
```

Answer (score 5):

**Spelling mistake**
id contentwrapper

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
```

Comment: Alas for him, as duly dash did take / away his function with but one mistake!